# Некорректно работает функция WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У меня есть вот такая функция, она работает с OpenAI, и генерит описание для товара. Но когда я его запускаю для примерно 5 товаров он выдаёт ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE и так раз на раз. Для одного товара всё спокойно происходит. В чем может быть проблема? Функция для WordPress.

```
    $products = get_posts($args);
    $open_ai = new OpenAi($this->api_key);
    $count=0;
    foreach ($products as $product) {   
             $text="Опиши товар '" . $product->post_title . "' от 600 до 800 символов";         
             echo $text."<BR><BR>";
             $complete = $open_ai->completion([
            'model' => 'text-davinci-003',
            'prompt' => $text,
            'temperature' => 0.7,
            'top_p'=>1,
            'max_tokens' => 1000,
            ]);
            $data = json_decode($complete);
            $new_text = $data->choices[0]->text;
            echo $new_text."<BR><BR>";
            wp_update_post([
            'ID' => $product->ID,
            'post_content' => $new_text,
            ]);
  }
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/wp-debug

Comment: А тут и без дебаггера ясно, что 5 запросов у OpenAI занимают слишком много времени и скрипт падает. Или OpenAI ограничивает частоту запросов и скрипт падает. Хотите обработать много товаров - используйте Action Scheduler.